# (InDesign CC 2019) Continuous page numbering was cancelled and each file in Book Panel has own page number?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book

I have a *Book file* includes 161 .inDDs files inside it. Some files have one page and some of them have more than five pages and etc, Before I updated *InDesign* to the last version, the Book panel showed the correct continuous page numbering and started from 1 to 257. But When I updated to the last version of InDesign and open the Book file, the continuous page numbering was canceled and now each .indd file has an own page number and each one starts from number 1.

I checked out "**Document Numbering Options**" feature from Book Panel pop-up menu, and it's set to "**Automatic Page Numbering**". I confused totally and don't understand why the Book Panel doesn't show continuous page numbering and I can't find the origin this weird problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try **Updating All Numbers** from the Book panel popup menu?

[image]

Go to the Indesign Preferences and check if **General** → **Page Numbering** is set to **Section Numbering** instead Absolute Numbering.
Then **Update All Numbers**.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it a few times, but nothing has changed!

Comment: Answer updated with another solution attempt.

Comment: That' it! It's fixed and now numbering back to the previous situation that I had. I accidentally sat "Page Numbering" to "Absolute" form and it ruined my document. Forgot that simple option, need to study simple options again! Thank You Danielillo!

Comment: I was in semi-agony for five days until the right search words ("InDesign book and chapter continuous pagination" offered a link to this page. I still had to do some disentangling but I wouldn't have had the first clue without you. (Adobe Support was no support.) Thanks to you, I finally got my chapters back in continuous sequence. The relief is enormous. I can't express my thanks too much.